# the armature doesn't move the mesh and i can't unparent the mesh for it to work

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, parent

I'm trying to rig a model that i didn't make in Blender (I made it in the game Spore). This is my first time trying to rig something.

But when I try to parent the armature to the body, it doesn't move the model in pose mode, and it's probably because the mesh is parented to the body, but no matter what I try, the mesh stays in the body and iI can't parent the armature to the mesh.

I tried unparenting it by alt P and doing clear parent, but it does nothing.

It won't let me drag the mesh into the collection either, and if I try to drag the armature into the mesh, it only lets me put it under body and it still doesn't work correctly in pose mode.

How do i unparent the mesh and get the armature to connect to the model properly?

here is the blend file if it's needed

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qNtb9bRdrOd5NVWW2QlNPMqM1l0gL_r5

[image: the hierarchy]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's multiple reasons the mesh isn't deforming as expected. The advice below is based on the blend file provided.

1. The mesh needs the 'armature' modifier, it currently has no modifiers.
2. The mesh needs weight painting, currently the mesh is unweighted / has no vertex groups.
3. It's a good idea to set the armature as the parent, but in this case that may not work as expected as they have different transformations. To fix that, select both the mesh and the armature and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Apply All Transforms*. Then you can parent as expected.

I strongly recommend checking out basic rigging tutorials before proceeding (there are a ton of great resources on YouTube and other places).

Answer (score 0):

You have vertices overlapping. In Edit mode, select all the vertices and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge By Distance*. Play with the value in the *Operator* box in the bottom left of your 3D view (but the default value is ok). The parent *With Automatic Weight*. You'll have to make some corrections though.

Comment: i did all of those things and it did remove the vertices, but the armature still wasn't synced with the mesh after i parented it. what corrections do i have to make? i'm still new to Blender.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple disconnected objects in your mesh, and for one reason or another the algorithm can't solve situations like that. Try and connect all the different objects in your creature, then parent with auto weights.